# Element intersects when leaving the animation causing it start (and stop) animation in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I have an issue with the `IntersectionObserver`, I tried to create an animation that would slide the element up into the screen by using `transformY()`. It worked, until I tried to scroll down and found an issue with this configuration: when I scrolled down far enough for the element to be hidden above my screen, it tried to stop the animation (go back down) but since it was now visible to me again, it went up to do the animation, then down. then up and so on. Here's a simulated environment with the same issue:

```html
<style>
    body {
        height: 200vh;
    }

    .container {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 100vh;
    }

    .animated {
        transform: translateY(200%);
        transition: all 1s;
        width: 150px;
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .animated.animate {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="animated">
            <p>I'm an animated div!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const animate = document.querySelectorAll(".animated")
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((elements) => {
            elements.forEach(element => {
                if (element.isIntersecting) {
                element.target.classList.toggle("animate");
            } else {
                element.target.classList.remove("animate");
            } 
            });
        });
        animate.forEach(element => {
            observer.observe(element)
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

If you scroll down to the very bottom, the animated div will pop in and out on top of the screen

I tried changing the `translateY()` values, changing the observer values etc. None of the solutions seemed to help

Comment: Just to be clear, if the div goes completely out of the top of the screen you want it to stay out? Is that right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. but I want it to still play the animation if I
it appears when I  scroll from top to bottom